# using iOS simulator 7.0 on Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode

On XCode 5.1.1 I didn't find iOS simulator 7.0 from Xcode -> preference -> Components. I wonder if I could install a simulator 7.0 on Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: xcodo 5.1.1 comes with iOS 7.1 simulator by default.. Go to XCode -> Open Developer tools -> More developer tools to download iOS 7.0 simulator dmg

Comment: alternative t download if u hav Xcode 5.0 just copy the `iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk` to Xcode 5.1.1 for example, right click `Xcode 5.0`-> `show package contents` -> `contents` -> `Developer` -> `Platforms` -> `iPhoneSimulator.platform` -> `Developer` -> `SDKs`-> `iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk` copy this and past t same location (above path as mentioned ) in  Xcode 5.1.1 after this relaunch the Xcode 5.1.1 ... :)